# Static default gateway on FreeBSD 8.0

Tags: freebsd, gateway

on FreeBSD i know i can use the route command to add a default gateway like this: route add default 192.168.1.254

but this does not save on a reboot. How can i get it to save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have your custom default gateway saved across reboots, you'll want to edit `/etc/rc.conf`. There is a directive in there called **defaultrouter** which is set to **NO** by default. The line looks like this:

```
defaultrouter="NO"
```

open `/etc/rc.conf` in your editor of choice, find this line, and change **NO** to the IP address of the gateway so it looks like this:

```
defaultrouter="192.168.1.254"
```

this will be persistent across reboots.